# MySQL Select Update guidance, query does not execute

Tags: mysql

This does not work, I am getting following error. I know why, because I cannot select and update on same tables. Can someone help/guide me in the right direction?

```
update 
    episode 
set 
    update_wp = 1 
where 
    episode_id in(
        select 
            e.episode_id 
        from 
            collection c 
        inner join 
            season s on s.collection_id = c.collection_id 
        inner join 
            episode e on e.season_id = s.season_id  
        where 
            c.title ='mom'
        );
```

MySQL Response:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'episode' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use following query:

```
UPDATE episode e, collection c, season s 
   SET e.update_wp = 1 
   WHERE 
     e.season_id = s.season_id AND 
     s.collection_id = c.collection_id AND 
     c.title = 'mom';
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't let you update tables which you are using in the select clause.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/664577) for more details.

There are several workarounds, one of which is to wrap the select clause with other select statement (**warning**: inefficient).

```
update 
    episode 
set 
    update_wp = 1 
where 
    episode_id in (
      select in_episode_id from (
        select 
            e.episode_id as in_episode_id
        from 
            collection c 
        inner join 
            season s on s.collection_id = c.collection_id 
        inner join 
            episode e on e.season_id = s.season_id  
        where 
            c.title ='mom'
      )
    ) as x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    update t1
    set 
        t1.update_wp = 1 
    from episode t1
    join
    (
            select 
                e.episode_id 
            from 
                collection c 
            inner join 
                season s on s.collection_id = c.collection_id 
            inner join 
                episode e on e.season_id = s.season_id  
            where 
                c.title ='mom'
    )t2
    t1.episode_id=t2.episode_id
```